# Vertically concatenating multidimensional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional matrix `J` of size `2`-by-`7`-by-`N` that I want to concatenate in vertically into a `2*N`-by-`7` matrix.

So for example:

```
>> J(:,:,1:2)

ans(:,:,1) =

1.0000         0         0    0.2263         0    0.0069    0.4996
     0    1.0000         0    1.4156         0   -0.1665    0.0208

ans(:,:,2) =

2.0000         0         0   -0.3432         0   -0.0069    0.4996
     0    3.0000         0    1.3919         0    0.1665    0.0208
```

Needs to be concatenated to

```
1.0000         0         0    0.2263         0    0.0069    0.4996
     0    1.0000         0    1.4156         0   -0.1665    0.0208
2.0000         0         0   -0.3432         0   -0.0069    0.4996
     0    3.0000         0    1.3919         0    0.1665    0.0208
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to rearrange the order of the dimensions and then [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to change it to a `2*N`-by-`7` matrix:

```
reshape(permute(J, [1,3,2]),[],size(J,2));
```

The reason you need the `permute` is because MATLAB is column-major meaning it stores elements of multidimensional arrays as vectors by going down the columns first. So when you call reshape it first looks down the columns and then moves on to the next column when it runs out of rows. Since you want to stack your 3rd dimension under your 1st dimension you need to make sure that when `reshape` runs out of rows it goes to that third dimension. Since `reshape` actually goes to the second dimension you need to use `permute` to swap your second and third dimensions.

Just for fun, here is another way to do it:

```
J2 = permute(J, [2,1,3]);
J2(:,:).'
```

And a third using [comma-separated-lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) instead

```
C = mat2cell(J, size(J,1), size(J,2), ones(1,1,size(J,3)));
cat(1,C{:})   %// Or vertcat(C{:})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for the help, much appreciated.